# Website search function working from one location but not another

Tags: networking, routing, database

The company I work for does a lot of business with a government program, U.S. General Services Administration. Their website is located [here](http://www.gsaadvantage.gov).

For the last two weeks, we have been unable to perform searches on this site. The website will load up fine, but searches always time out (error message says could not connect to 169.254.0.0, which makes me think it is a network issue). I first thought they were having issues with their database, so I notified their IT guys. However, today they have told me that the problem is not on their end.

Just for kicks, I VNC'd into my machine at home and tried to replicate the problem. Amazingly, everything functioned as normal! So the problem seems to be isolated to our company's location. Problem can be replicated on both Linux and Windows machines, using Chrome, Firefox, and IE. Tried erasing cache, cookies, etc. Flushed DNS.

I'm pulling my hair out here. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Your question says almost nothing about what you were doing or what happened when you did it, making it impossible to attempt to reproduce, or even guess at what might be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a VPN between your location and theirs?  If it acts differently from your home PC than at work, then I'd concentrate on differences there. A VPN may allow you to view the site but may block other access to the network.  Another possibility is your DNS server,  you said you flushed DNS, by which I assume you mean you flushed it on the local machine.  You may need to flush the DNS cache on our network's DNS server(s).

Comment: Doh, didn't even think about the cache on the server. Thanks, that did the trick!

Comment: No problem,  glad it helped.